# RxJS scan can only access last pushed partial data

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a `BehaviorSubject` that I want to update by passing a `Partial<Type>` so I have this code. Then the `scan` handles the merge between new and old data.

```
personUpdates$ = new BehaviorSubject<Partial<Person>>({});

person$ = this.personUpdates$.pipe(
  scan((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {
    name: '',
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
  } as Person)
);

updatePerson = (person: Partial<Person>) => {
  this.personUpdates$.next(person);
}
```

But the problem I have is to access the data in certain places. For example if i subscribe and log `person$` in my constructor I can see the whole object no issues. But if I try to access it in other places I only receive the last updated value.

```
constructor() {
  // Always have the full object
  this.person$.subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
}

checkValues = () => {
  // Only have the last Partial values
  this.person$.pipe(first()).subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
};
```

How can I make sure I always get the whole object?

I have reproduced the issue in a [StackBlitz Sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-module-sandbox-tnktz2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I think the reason for this is that checkValues is only subscribed when you click on the button ! constructor is subscribed as soon as component is loaded.  If you see the documentation here https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject, behavior subject only emits the latest value, so i am suspecting checkValues part subscription only happens later. If you however, click that button first you should get full object ?

Comment: @kuldeep I get that, by how can i achieve desired result? I mean i can just spread the BehaviorSubject.value but that is generally frowned upon and I would like to find a alternative :D

Comment: may be then subscribe once and use value everywhere, if it is the same component. Otherwise i would basically allow .next only from within a service lets say, and expose AsObservable to outer world so that anyone from outside can simply subscribe and receive full object

Comment: @kuldeep That's what i'm doing but I have the same issue when exposing the public since i cant access any of my values

Comment: @AndrewAllen I have tried replaysubject, sharereplay and still getting exact same behavior. I think my general thought process maybe need reworking? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`person$` needs to save its calculations for late subscribers,

use `shareReplay(1)`

```
  personUpdates$ = new BehaviorSubject<Partial<Person>>({});

  person$ = this.personUpdates$.pipe(
    scan((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {
      name: '',
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
    } as Person),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

Comment: I had tried the shareReplay everywhere expect there! :D